# Spring Batch error recovery : best practices and design pattern

Tags: spring, design-patterns, database-design, spring-batch

We have a batch that treat a huge amount of data, when things goes well it send an email for each row of data that he treat. When things goes wrong ( missing data for example ) the batch has not to be stoped, it has to continue processing other data.. Our problem here, is when we want to repeat the treatment for thoes wrong data ( manualy or by replaying the batch and passing a param, like recoveryMode=true), We want to do something more generic that let us know the corrupted data ( generic for this batch or an otherone) , and beging the treatment from those data..

Are there any known principles, best-practices , design patterns or schema best design to solve recovery mode problems ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring Batch documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/) provides an excellent guide for those new to the framework.
In particular, please pay close attention to the [Common Batch Patterns](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#patterns) and [Retry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/retry.html) sections.